# clear back stack of activities

Tags: android

I have some activities A, B, C, D. No the way it's set up is like this.

1. When user starts the app, activity A starts.
2. Based on a preference, which if set to true, immediately starts activity D
3. From there D starts C and C starts B which then starts A

... At this point i want D, C, B removed from the back stack so that user cant go back to them by pressing back from A (but the back button should work like it should when in D, B, C).

so to sum it up i need something like this
`D <--> C <--> B --> A`

I tried using intent flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` & `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`
but they dont work.
How do i accomplish this??

Comment: You should try to startActivityForResult then you should handle with result... If it's come back from A then you should finish them, too. Otherwise they'll just do what they're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Then start activity A with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME` flag set.

Ok.

How about calling finish on B after launching A?

Comment: This is what i am doing right now 
`Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);   main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   startActivity(main);
finish();`

Comment: I think, do not add new task. leave the remaining and check

Comment: how about giving more info. Put out your code here. There might be more at play. In most cases, this should do the trick IMHO.

Comment: the code is the same on all activities to start the next activity

`Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME); 
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(main); 
finish();`

the name of the class just changes. As you can see i tried different combination of flags but it didn't work.

Comment: let me see if i can check this, and i'll get back to you

Comment: I ended up overriding onResume on the activities i didn't want to go back to and calling finish if conditions checks out.

Comment: i'm not sure I follow ` i didn't want to go back to and calling finish if conditions checks out.` but anyway if you got this working, you should consider adding it as an answer and accepting it

Comment: I used `protected void onResume() {
  if (goBackNotAllowed){
   finish();
  }
  super.onResume();
 }`